# Does Ubuntu support touchscreen laptops?

Tags: touchscreen

Is it possible to use a touchscreen display on a laptop with Ubuntu, as in like, being able to scroll with my touchscreen and stuff?

Comment: touch screen is similar to any input device such as a mouse, but the technology is relatively new so it does not work in all applications.